# Remove [zip-drive] tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

A single question (about how to recover data from the obsolete drive).  Although, it's possible that a museum or archaeology team could post a question asking to identify a relic.

[zip-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zip-drive)

Comment: Tough call. It's a really good tag in general, and it fits the single question perfectly, *but* it's also pretty useless.

Comment: I'm just thinking there might not be a lot of future call for it.

Answer (score 5):

Just because there's only one question (currently!) for a tag, does not mean that the tag is useless or unwarranted.

- It's specific (a type of hardware)
- It's unambiguous (not going to be confused with other types of drives or [software](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zip))
- It adequately categorises it's question.
- If another zip-drive question is asked, the tag will exist for the new asker to use.

Single-use tags aren't always bad. A topic may be small enough that only one or two questions are asked, and that's ok! It's the ambiguous meta-tags we need to watch out for.

I think this tag is fine. Indeed, searching for '[zip drive is:question](https://superuser.com/search?q=zip%20drive%20is%3Aquestion)' yielded some other results that should utilise the same tag

<sub>(I can't remember where but someone made the argument for single-use tags better than I can, if I find it I'll link it)</sub>